# determining if process has terminated successfully

Tags: python, bash, unix

I have some code to execute the unix shell command in background in python

```
 import subprocess
 process = subprocess.Popen('find / > tmp.txt &',shell=True)
```

I need to capture the scenario where i come to know that process has finished successful
 completion .

Please explain with sample code

Tazim

Comment: Just another note that `shell=True` is also unnecessary since the command you're passing is a string and a shell must be spawned to evaluate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use shell=True.  It is bad for your health.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['find', '/'], stdout=open('tmp.txt', 'w'))
if proc.wait() == 0:
  pass
```

If you really need a file, use `import tempfile` instead of a hard-coded temporary file name.  If you don't need the file, use a pipe (see the subprocess docs as Thomas suggests).

Also, don't write shell scripts in Python.  Use the `os.walk` function instead.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for the `&`: the command is launched in a separate process, and runs independently.

If you want to wait until the process terminates, use [`wait()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait):

```
process = subprocess.Popen('find / > tmp.txt', shell = True)
exitcode = process.wait()
if exitcode == 0:
    # successful completion
else:
    # error happened
```

If your program can do something meaningful in the meantime, you can use [`poll()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) to determine if the process has finished.

Furthermore, instead of writing the output to a temporary file and then reading it from your Python program, you can read from the pipe directly. See the [`subprocess` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) for details.